# How to return IEnumerable<T> collection if there is one yield

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

What is the smartest way to use return statement in iterator block instead of foreach if I want to return input collection?

```
public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
   if (someCondition)
   {
       // return collection; - cannot be used because of "yield" bellow
       foreach (T obj in collection)
       {
          yield return obj;
       } 
       yield break;
   }
   yield return new T();
}
```

Comment: I know that it is just a sample code but you really should not use 'class' as a name of variable :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that's all you can do within an iterator block. There's no equivalent of `yield!` in F#, or the idea of a `yield foreach`. It's unfortunate, but that's the way it is :(

Of course, you could avoid using an iterator block in the first place:

```
public IEnumerable<Class> Filter(IEnumerable<Class> collection)
{
   return someCondition ? collection : Enumerable.Repeat(new Class(2), 1);
}
```

Or if you have more complex logic:

```
public IEnumerable<Class> Filter(IEnumerable<Class> collection)
{
   return someCondition ? collection : FilterImpl(collection);
}

private IEnumerable<Class> FilterImpl(IEnumerable<Class> collection)
{
    yield return new Class(2);
    yield return new Class(1);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would probably do:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
   if (someCondition)
   {
       return collection
   }
   return new [] {new T()};
}
```

In more complex cases, where some collections are optionally included in the return value, I use `Union`.